# How to create a process that should not be listed in ps -ef command in linux

Tags: python, c

I want to create a process that should not be listed in ps -ef command, while the process is running. I need this for testing an Intrusion detection system (IDS) application in Linux.

Comment: Is the application in `C` or `Python` or both?

Comment: There's no way to run a process without having it listed by `ps`. (If it is not listed, it's no *process*, by definition). You can, however, *run code* that is no process on its own, for example by hi-jacking another process or by intruding into kernel code.

Comment: You can produce some kernel module that will hide your process from appearing in `procfs` for example. But that's another story..

Comment: @sjsam, this application is in c.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible without modifying either kernel or ps itself. Simple process can't hide itself. But you can change process name by changing `argv[0]` and mimicry to another common process, like httpd, sshd, etc - that's what a lot of malware does.